# Return authors sorted by the number of publications meeting tags criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

**Context:**
I have authors. Each author has published one or several publications (it could be more than 500).
Each publication contains tags (the average is 50, the maximum is 445).

**My first question:**
I'd like to know how easy it is to create the query to return authors sorted by the number of publications regarding a selection of tags (between 1 and 10 tags).

If the criteria are 2 tags for example, I want authors having published publications having both tags.

**Labels**
Publications, Authors, and Tags would be Labels.
And I would have relationships between Publications and Authors. And between Publications and Tags.

I'm happy to hear any suggestion to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Your tags are items in a list? Labels? Also, can you provide a sample data set and the expected result?

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about your graph structure?

Comment: There is no way to tell whether you need a "powerful" machine for any given data size. That's not important, it only implies the space requirements. You will need as powerful a machine as you need to get the results that you want; you would need to have some idea of desired query latency, query throughput, data throughput, usage, etc. to determine how "powerful" a machine you need.

Comment: @Bruno Peres My first idea was to have tags as Labels and not as items in a list. I'm gonna try your solution with tags as items in a list. I would have preferred as Labels because I thought it would have been more flexible - but I'm a beginner so I don't know.

Comment: @floatingpurr I would like Publication, Author, and Tag as Labels. A link between Publication and Author, and between Publication and Tag.

Comment: @Rebecca Nelson Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question I wrote a Cypher query using [all()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-all) function to ensure that publications contains all tags specified in the declared list. Also, all articles are collected and ordered descending. Take a look:

```
with ['tag1', 'tag2'] as tags
match (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article)
where all (tag in tags where tag in article.tags)
with author, collect(article) as articles order by size(articles) desc
return author
```

Your second question is hard to answer. What is your definition of a "powerful machine"? Also, it depends on other factors than the data set size. The queries you are running over this dataset and the number of concurrent access are good examples, I think.

Comment: I've tried your example, it works! I'm gonna try the one of @floatingpurr that is more what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following query based on @floatingpurr and @Bruno Peres answers:

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:PUBLISHED]->(publication:Publication)
MATCH (publication)-[:TAGGED]->(tag:Tag)
WHERE tag.name IN ['Tag 2', 'Tag 3']
RETURN author, count(*) AS numberOfPublications
ORDER BY numberOfPublications DESC
```

I'm not happy with the count since it doesn't count unique publication. If a publication contains the Tag 2 and Tag 3 (the tag in the criteria) then it will count as 2. I'd like it counts like 1.

I don't know how to use the distinct feature in that case. Also I don't know if it's the optimised version. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a `distinct` clause in the `count` function. `MATCH (author:Author)-[:PUBLISHED]->(publication:Publication)
MATCH (publication)-[:TAGGED]->(tag:Tag)
WHERE tag.name IN ['Tag 2', 'Tag 3']
RETURN author, count(distinct publication) AS numberOfPublications
ORDER BY numberOfPublications DESC`

Comment: @Bruno It's great! It's what I wanted to achieve! Thanks.